# Java unicode escape with more than 4 hexadecimal digits

Tags: java, ant

A Java properties file generated by the Ant `<propertyfile>` task contains the unicode escape `\u000151` for the Hungarian letter `ő`.

I expected `\u0151`, is it a bug in Ant? (Ant 1.8.0, Java 1.7.0)

(Based on the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) only a 4-digit unicode escape is considered valid...)

Comment: A bit late but please note that the posted JLS section is about Unicode in **source code**, and for files read by `Properties.load` - sure not for files read by `Properties.loadFromXML()` or any other method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I found no bug reports related to the issue, it is probably a bug, based on an official Oracle documentation: [Supplementary Characters in the Java Platform](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html)

This documentation states that one *supplementary character* can be represented by two *unicode escape*s:

> For cases where the character encoding used cannot represent the
>   characters directly, the Java programming language provides a Unicode
>   escape syntax. This syntax has not been enhanced to express
>   supplementary characters directly. Instead, they are represented by
>   the two consecutive Unicode escapes for the two code units in the
>   UTF-16 representation of the character. For example, the character
>   U+20000 is written as "\uD840\uDC00".

This document also specifies a syntax for representing a *unicode escape* syntax for *text input* (i.e. it is not supported by Java at language level):

> For text input, the Java 2 SDK provides a code point input method
>   which accepts strings of the form "\Uxxxxxx", where the uppercase "U"
>   indicates that the escape sequence contains six hexadecimal digits,
>   thus allowing for supplementary characters. A lowercase "u" indicates
>   the original form of the escape sequences, "\uxxxx".

It means that the Ant `<propertyfile>` task is incorrect, it should generate `\u0151` or `\U000151` instead of `\u000151` (note the uppercase/lowercase U) - at least based on the documentation above.

But in practice the \Uxxxxxx syntax seems to be unsupported:

[test.properties]

```
key1=\u0151
key2=\u000151
key3=\U000151
```

[PropertiesParserTest.java]

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PropertiesParserTest {
    @Test
    public void testLoad() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.properties")) {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(input);

            // Valid unicode escape
            assertEquals("ő", p.getProperty("key1"));

            // The 6-digit unicode escape generated by Ant is incorrect
            assertEquals("\u0001" + "51", p.getProperty("key2"));

            // \Uxxxxxx is not supported
            assertEquals("U000151", p.getProperty("key3"));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenerate() throws IOException {
        Properties p1 = new Properties();
        p1.setProperty("key1", "ő");
        p1.setProperty("key2", "\u000151");
        // Not supported in practice: p.setProperty("key3", "\U000151");

        File file = File.createTempFile("PropertiesParserTest_", ".properties");
        System.out.println(file);

        try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            p1.store(output, null);
        }

        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            Properties p2 = new Properties();
            p2.load(input);

            // Valid unicode escape
            assertEquals("ő", p2.getProperty("key1"));

            // The 6-digit unicode escape generated by Ant is incorrect
            assertEquals("\u0001" + "51", p2.getProperty("key2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good place to start reading about Unicode sequences is Javadoc for class Character: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html. I can not say for sure if this is a bug but it looks like a bug. Also you probably can use a utility that converts any text into unicode sequences and vise-versa to play with this issue. You can find the link to an open source library that has such utility among others in this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles). Look for paragraph in the article "**String Unicode converter**"

Comment: I just checked with the utility I mentioned above. I converted both escape sequences \u0151 and \u000151 and they both were recognized and converted to letter ő. So I guess the sequence  \u000151 is a valid and recognizable.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't get how it is parsed. Eg. when the parser sees "\u000151" how does it make the decision that it is a "\u0001" followed by the string "51", or it is the single character "\u000151". I think this is strange behavior...

Comment: If you read the javadoc for Character class (the one I referenced) you will see that there are valid unicode sequences that are longer then 4 digits. So the parsers need to know how to handle them. Also when I converted back the letter ő to the sequence I got back the expected \u0151.

Comment: "there are valid unicode sequences that are longer then 4 digits": I don't find any...

Comment: In Java 8 API for class Character, under the paragraph "Unicode Character Representations" you can find the following quote "The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF" Read the whole paragraph there for explanations on Unicode raqnge: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: ""The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF"" - Yes, that's clear. But it does not mean that Java supports all of them at language level, see the same docs: "In this representation, supplementary characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF)"

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I don't have clear answer for you beyond what I said on this issue. Just to sum up what I said is that a Unicode converter was able to read and correctly parse sequence "\u000151" to letter ő. However when converting letter ő into Unicode sequence converter gives "\u0151" as expected. So, it is my guess that sequence "\u000151" is acceptable while somewhat not expected. Perhaps it is parsed because preceding "0"s are simply discarded, just like it would be valid to say that 0043 = 043 = 43.