# Given the number of a Unicode code point, how can I obtain a String or CharSequence object for that character

Tags: java, unicode, character, codepoint

I have seen Questions and Answers about obtaining the code point number of a Unicode character in Java. For example, the Question [*How can I get a Unicode character's code?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006533/642706).

But I want the opposite: given an integer number, how do I get text of that character assigned to that [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number?

The `char` primitive data type is of no use, being limited to only the [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29) of the Unicode character set. That plane represents approximately the first 64,000 characters defined in Unicode. But Unicode has grown to nearly double that, over 113,000 characters defined now. The numbers assigned to characters range over a million. Being based on [16-bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit_computing), a `char` is limited to a range of 64K, not nearly enough.

Both [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) and [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) classes offer the method [`codePointAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt(java.lang.CharSequence,int)) to examine a character and return an `int` representing the code point assigned in Unicode. I am looking for the opposite.

➥ Given an `int`, how to get an object of [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html), [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), or some implementation of [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) that I can then join to other text?

When writing string literals, we can use a Unicode escape sequence with the backslash-with-u. But I am interested in **working with integer variables**, soft-coding rather than hardcoding the Unicode characters.

Comment: Inside of a string, use a unicode escape. "\u0c30" That is, I believe, the Greek letter pi. The unicode character number is in hex.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks but my intention behind this question was to work with integer variables. I'll edit Question to clarify. And, by the way, that escape sequence is [not so simple when you have more than four hex digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37679763/642706).

Comment: Yes, I know. Unicode support becomes more complex, quickly. You'll need to read the official java documentation about unicode support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
String s = Character.toString( 128_567 ) ;
```

> 

## Details

You asked for an object of `Character`, `String`, or some implementation of `CharSequence`.

### `Character`

The `Character` class is actually [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), a mere object wrapper around the primitive `char` type. The `char` type is legacy too, being defined internally as a 16-bit number limited to the first 64K of Unicode code points. Unicode now has more than twice than number of code points assigned to characters, so `char` fails to represent most characters.

So we cannot instantiate a `Character` object for a character outside the [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) set of characters. So, as a workaround, `Character.toString( int )` produces a `String` containing a single character. `String` *can* handle any and all Unicode characters, while `Character` cannot.

### `String`  `Character.toString( int )`

To get a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) object containing a single character determined by an `int`, pass the `int` to [`Character.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

As an example, we use [`FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK`](https://emojipedia.org/face-with-medical-mask/), an emoji character at [U+1F637](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf) (decimal: 128,567).

```
// -----|  input  |----------------
String input = "" ;                                 // FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK at code point U+1F637 (decimal: 128,567).
int codePoint = input.codePointAt( 0 ) ;              // Returns 128,567. 
System.out.println( "codePoint : " + codePoint ) ;
```

> codePoint : 128567

Convert that `int` primitive variable to a `String`.

```
// -----|  String  |----------------
String output = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;     // Pass an `int` primitive integer number.
System.out.println( "output : " + output ) ;
```

> output :

Or use a literal integer number.

```
String output2 = Character.toString( 128_567 ) ;      // Pass an integer literal.
System.out.println( "output2 : " + output2 ) ;
```

> output2 :

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/NU2aUJ).

### `CharSequence`

The code above works, as [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) is an implementation of [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

```
CharSequence cs = Character.toString( 128_567 ) ;     // Returns a `String` which is a `CharSequence`.
```

### `appendCodePoint`

The [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class offers a method [`appendCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint(int)) to add a character via its assigned Unicode code point number. [Ditto](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#appendCodePoint(int)) for thread-safe [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).